# How to append an empty array by multiple 1D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, append

I want to create 2D array by multiple 1D array `(1,7680)` to have multiple number of arrays under each other creating 2D array `(n,7680)`

Any help would be appreciated

**code**

```
y=[]
t=0
movement=int(S*256)
if(S==0):
    movement=_SIZE_WINDOW       
while data.shape[1]-(t*movement+_SIZE_WINDOW) > 0:
    for i in range(0, 22):
        start = t*movement
        stop = start+_SIZE_WINDOW
        signals[i,:]=data[i,start:stop]
        y=np.append(signals[i,:],y)

     t=t+1
```

Comment: Please explain in more detail.

Comment: You wrote `np.empty(())`. Are you using `numpy`? If that is true maybe you would need to add the `numpy` tag to your question.

Comment: @AnnZen I want to create 2D array by multiple 1D array `(1,7680)` to have multiple number of arrays under each other creating 2D array

Comment: Appending arrays to other arrays one by one is an extremely inefficient way to use NumPy, due to the quadratic amount of copying involved. Build up a list of arrays one by one and then convert to a single array at the end, or preallocate the whole array up front and fill in chunks one by one.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica How can I do that ?? I want to create 2D array by multiple 1D array to have multiple number of arrays under each other creating 2D array

Comment: You start with a empty list, `y=[]`, but then switch to using `np.append`.  Why didn't you stick with `y.append()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the shape of the arrays you want to create is well defined the easiest and optimal way to do so is to create an empty array like this:

```
array_NxM = np.empty((N,M))
```

This will create an empty array with the desired shape, then you can fill the array by iterating through its elements.

Creating an array by appending 1d arrays is definitely not optimal but an acceptable way to do so would be to create a list, appending 1d arrays to it and then cast the list to a numpy array like this:

```
array_NxM = []
for i in range(M):
    array_NxM.append(array_1xM)
array_NxM = np.array(array_NxM)
```

The worst way to do this is definitely to use np.append. If possible always avoid appending to a numpy array as this operations leads to a full copy in memory of the array and a read/write of it.

Comment: I add this to my code`array_NxM = []
            for J in range(7681):
                array_NxM.append(data[i,start:stop])
                array_NxM = np.array(array_NxM)` but I got this error `array_NxM.append(data[i,start:stop])
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'`

Comment: You cannot use append to a numpy array. Just use the first solution, it will produce what you need

Comment: I don't know the shape of the array to use this `array_NxM = np.empty((N,M))` .

Comment: What is the first solution ??